# Java sockets, server send message to multiple clients

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

I am one server and multiple clients via threads. The client(s) send their message to the server. I have worked out how to make the server send the message back to client like a echo system. If I have two clients, I want them to send their message to the server and the server should send it to the client that did not send the message i.e. the other client. How would I go about send the message back to all the clients apart from the one that send the message?

Answer (score 0):

When the message comes in, determine what the userID / other identifying id the incoming message is associated with. Then re-broadcast to all other sockets, but exclude the Socket associated with the ID that sent the message

Answer (score 0):

Make at the server side a list with all the clients... 
every time a new msg is received, then iterate the list and send the msg using the port of the socket as id...

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a Chat program too. What I did was, I had a class `ClientHandler` that handles the connection for each individual client.

Inside `ClientHandler` I had a `HashMap`. I added each client that had connected to the `HashMap`, with the `Key` being the `client id`. I used a [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) rather than `int` for the `client id`.

Inside this handler class, I had a `sendMessage(String str)` method. Within this method, a `for-each` loop that loops through each `ClientHandler` object, checking the `values` inside the `HashMap`. Inside this `for-each` loop, I have an `if` statement that checks whether you are writing to the `ClientHandler` object with `this` id. If the check returns `false`, you go ahead and write the message on the `PrintWriter` and the message **won't** be sent to the client writing the message.

This worked for **me**. Might not work for **you**.